# Replace empty string with with np.nan but got 'NaN'

Tags: numpy, pandas

I tried to replace empty string with `np.nan`

But I got `None` in cells , what wrong with that ?

Thanks

```
df.replace('', np.nan)
```

[image]

Comment: Your title says that you get 'NaN'? (which is the expected thing). But can you show a reproducible example? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

There must be a problem with your data, and not with pandas. See bellow an example:

```
>>> data = [['a', 'b', ''], ['', 'e', 'f']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  a  b   
1     e  f
```

If you try to replace `''` with `np.nan` in the above example, you get the desired result:

```
>>> df.replace('', np.nan)
     0  1    2
0    a  b  NaN
1  NaN  e    f
```

However, if by any chance your data was not correctly specified:

```
>>> data = [['a', 'b', None], [None, 'e', 'f']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
      0  1     2
0     a  b  None  
1  None  e     f
```

`pandas` cannot help, as your data does not contain empty strings, but non-specified values (`None`):

```
>>> df.replace('', np.nan) 
      0  1     2
0     a  b  None
1  None  e     f
```

However, there is still a chance you can remove the `None`s from your table. The following, as silly as it sounds, should still work:

```
>>> df.replace(np.nan, np.nan)
     0  1    2
0    a  b  NaN
1  NaN  e    f
```

It is hard to say without having your raw data, but hope the above helps.

Answer (score 0):

`df.replace` works only for pandas dataframe.

Kindly check the type of your variable by `type(df)`. It can be a `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` because of which you can see that difference.

The following code works,

```
data = data.to_pandas() #convert pyspark pandas DF to pandas DF
data.replace("", np.NaN, inplace = True) # replace empty string to NaN
```

Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html